# What was the reason behind carving Lord Ram's name on the boulders of Ram Setu Bridge?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama

- All **websites and television shows** say **Lord Ram's Name** was carved on the **boulders of Ram Setu Bridge** that was built by Vanara Army.

**ACCORDING to [SCRIPTURES](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga22/yuddha_22_frame.htm):**

- Nala had a Boon that he can make stones float.

> O, excellent man! This one, named Nala, a glorious person, is the son of Vishvakarma; who was given a boon by his father and is equal to Visvakarma. Let this greatly energetic monkey build a bridge across me. I can hold that bridge. He is just the same as his father.

- There was **not mentioned any reason** for carving Lord Ram's Name on rocks.

**MY QUESTION**

- What was the **reason behind carving Lord Ram's Name** on the boulders of Ram Setu Bridge ?

[image: Rama setu bridge]